# folder not visible on mounted drive

Tags: directory, data-recovery

OK, So i finished up copying some stuff(a lot actually) from my portable drive to my laptop and it finished just as expected.Then i needed to do some work on my windows installed on the same laptop so i unmounted the drives and it asked me to empty the trash in drive,so i did.

when i booted with windows i noticed that the stuff i copied wasnt there in those drive.I thought something was wrong with the windows. So finished the work and booted back to ubuntu.

And to my bad luck it didnt either showed any of the things that i copied to the drives.I checked the memory that the device was occupying and it was full (since i copied a lot of stuff).

So that means the files are still there just not accessible. I opened terminal and changed my current directory to the drive having my stuff and checked the list of folders in it and it says:

```
cannot access $RECYCLE.BIN: Input/output error
```

can someone help me with those files.

Comment: Please try searching the file to see if they are there. Open a terminal and run the command:

`find path_to_partition -type f -name "fileName"`

where path_to_partition should be replaced by the target where you want to search, and fileName by the name of the file (case sensitive) to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should boot to windows, and go to the recycle bin. If your files are there, you can restore the recycle bin.

May be you accidentally delete the files.

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: i dont think that is the case since my drive is still full.It should have been empty if i deleted the files